# How to read Excel cell's validations using office js?

Tags: office-js

How to read the already implemented data validations using office-js, I have read [this](https://dev.office.com/blogs/new-additions-to-excel-javascript-api) page, new api's are avilable in beta version, Now I am trying for how to implement this validation in excel?

Answer (score 1):

Docs about the data validation APIs are available in the [ExcelJS_OpenSpec](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/ExcelJs_OpenSpec).

Also, there's a Script Lab snippet that contains multiple examples of data validation in Excel. Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free: https://aka.ms/getscriptlab), then open the Script Lab **Code** window in Excel, select **Samples** in the navigation menu, and choose the **Data Validation** sample (located near the bottom of the **Samples** list, under the heading **Preview APIs**).

Once you've opened the snippet, you can view the code in the **Code** pane to see examples of data validation and test/run the snippet using the **Run** pane to see the data validation in action.  For example, the following function (from the snippet) adds a validation rule that requires a positive number:

```
async function addPositiveNumberRequirement() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        const rankingRange = sheet.tables.getItem("NameOptionsTable").columns.getItem("Ranking").getDataBodyRange();

        // When you are developing, it is a good practice to
        // clear the dataValidation object with each run of your code.
        rankingRange.dataValidation.clear();

        let greaterThanZeroRule = {
            wholeNumber: {
                formula1: 0,
                operator: Excel.DataValidationOperator.greaterThan
            }
        };
        rankingRange.dataValidation.rule = greaterThanZeroRule;

        rankingRange.dataValidation.prompt = {
            message: "Please enter a positive number.",
            showPrompt: true,
            title: "Positive numbers only."
        };

        rankingRange.dataValidation.errorAlert = {
            message: "Sorry, only positive numbers are allowed",
            showAlert: true,
            style: "Stop",
            title: "Negative Number Entered"
        };

        await context.sync();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried the sample data. But I am trying to read the validation in office.js, Means if I entered the wrong values through the script it is allowing, how can I overcome this?

Comment: @mkHun Data validation only validates user input, it does not validate programmatic input, so if you set values (or formulas) using office-js (or VBA or any other programmatic way for that matter), then it will allow you to set them, regardless of data validation.

Comment: @PhilipRueker -- thanks for the clarification about this.  Is it possible to programmatically (using the Office.js API) determine what, if any, data validation rules are in effect for a given range (i.e., so that a developer could proactively avoid writing data to the worksheet that violates data validation rules)?

Comment: @KimBrandl Not at the moment, but this is something on our feature backlog and may be added in our next feature wave.